# Capture Webservice response when data submitted through form in java

Tags: java, web-services, selenium

I am automating a form [Using Selenium WebDriver, Java ] where after filling the forms and submit, the data sends to webservice. Intern Webservice returns a campaign id but its not shown in form. For that i have press F12 and go network tab .. and so to see in chrome.

I have succesfully automated data entering in form and submission. Where am struck is to capture response sent by webservice. Is it possible to capture Webservice resonse in java when data was submitted through form.

Thanks in advance.
Narendra

Comment: Have you checked on the page to see if it has been updated with a hidden element that contains the campaign id?  If the webservice is passing that back, it would only be logical for something on the page to capture that information for use later.  the user just wouldn't see it in the page.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible directly using Selenium. Please check if you can use [browsermob-proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) which acts as a proxy between your WebDriver and the web application. Pleaser refer this [sample code](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium) for integrating it with Selenium. It can be used to capture all network traffic in HAR format.

Comment: If not directly by selenium, are there any third party jars to accomplish the same

Comment: Yes, my answer has link to **browsermob-proxy**. Please check if it suits your need.